# Alfred doesn't see Simulator app

Tags: spotlight, alfred

I installed Alfred on a 10.13 machine a few days ago and it doesn't see Simulator app.

I tried to reinstall Alfred, clear Alfred cache multiple times, rebuild Spotlight index. No luck.

It works fine on the other machines out of the box (as it always used to do).

Simulator folder is added to Alfred's paths.

What could be wrong here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you figured out? I had "simulator" keyword work on my previous mbp, but now it doesn't, ffs.

Comment: @AlexanderKim yes! I "cut" and "pasted" Simulator.app to Desktop and back to its original location. After that Alfred was able to find it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "cut" and "pasted" Simulator.app to Desktop and back to its original location. After that Alfred was able to find it

Comment: I just googled this issue, and found info that Apple removed all metadata from simulator app, so i just ended with doing own workflow to call this app, to avoid copying/pasting Simulator.app around.